# Export results from R to Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: r, excel

I tried to download the xlsx package but it doesn't seem to exist anymore.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `XLConnect`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
# save the results in excel
write.csv(results, file = "results_drivetime.csv")
```

Thanks to @Alpha Beta Gamma